# Convergence in L^p for function multiplied for another function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Problem: Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ and let  $f_{\epsilon}, f \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be functions such that $f_{\epsilon} \rightarrow f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$. Which condition should have another function $g$ so that
$$\int_{\Omega}g(x)f_{\epsilon}(x) \ dx \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} g(x)f(x) \ dx \ \ \ ?$$

Comment: If $g \in L^q(\Omega)$, then Holder's inequality shows this convergence holds (where $1/p + 1/q = 1$).

Comment: Where does this result came from?

Comment: The limit you wrote is equivalent to $\int_\Omega (f_\epsilon(x) - f(x)) g(x) \to 0$. Then you can apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality.